# Main Activity automatically started after Google sign in?

Tags: android, android-activity, firebase-authentication, google-signin

After the Google sign in through Firebase Auth, my app's Main Activity automatically started, even though I didn't make any `intent` to start it.

This is my **LoginActivty.java**:

```
// Email Password
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListner;
RelativeLayout LoginActivity;
private ProgressDialog mprogress;

//Database
private String userId;
FirebaseUser user;
DatabaseHelper myDb;
private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
private DatabaseReference myRef;

//Google Sign In
SignInButton mGoogleBtn;
private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 1;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiclient;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);

    mGoogleBtn = findViewById(R.id.googleSignIn);
    mGoogleBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    myRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference();
    myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    //Configure Google Sign In
    mprogress = new ProgressDialog(this);

    LoginActivity = findViewById(R.id.activity_login);
    mAuthListner = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {

            if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
                mprogress.dismiss();
            }
        }
    };

    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    mGoogleApiclient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .enableAutoManage(this, new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
                    mprogress.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Connection failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }).addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso).build();

}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    int btnId = view.getId();
    switch (btnId) {

        case R.id.googleSignIn:

            if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
                mprogress.setMessage("Signing In...");
                mprogress.show();
                mprogress.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                mprogress.setCancelable(false);
                signIn();

            } else {
                mprogress.dismiss();

            }

            break;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListner);
}

private void signIn(){
    Intent intent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiclient);
    startActivityForResult(intent,RC_SIGN_IN);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);

    if(requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {

        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);

        if(result.isSuccess()){
            GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
        }else{
            mprogress.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}

private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {

    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)

            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {

           Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, LoggedClientActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
            mprogress.dismiss();

        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

            mprogress.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
}
```

}

I want to start `LogClientActivity.class` after a successful authentication, but it starts `MainActivity.class`. How can I avoid that?

Answer (score 1):

You are using [`FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener) which is triggered  **when there is a change in the authentication state** which is actually starting your main activity so **remove this listener**

```
mAuthListner = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
        // a change in login state is acquired 
        // now there is a current user available so 
        // it will start the main activity
        if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
            mprogress.dismiss();
        }
    }
};
```

The `voidonAuthStateChanged(FirebaseAuth auth)` method gets invoked in the UI thread on changes in the authentication state as:

- Right after the listener has been registered
- **When a user is signed in**
- When the current user is signed out
- When the current user changes

Comment: Thanks **Pavneet_Singh** but if i remove authstatelistener how i detect if the user is signed in or not if he is i want to start MainActivity.

Comment: @ShashankBaghel you can do `mAuth.getCurrentUser()!=null` so if `true` mean user is logged in or `false` mean not